# .NET Core application fails to find CA cert on Linux even after putting the certificates in ca cert store of openssl

Tags: c#, linux, ssl, .net-core, openssl

.NET Core applications fail with "RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors" on linux even after copying the CA certificates to "/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors" and then running "update-ca-trust"

Answer (score 0):

After creating the CA cert with basic constraints CA:true, the application worked fine.